# How do I Make MEAN.io app public? Why am I seeing getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I have a MEAN.io app that I edit and test on my local machine. When I run grunt, the app will startup and I can then open a browser and navigate to `http://localhost:3000` and everything runs fine.

I would like to put this app on my server and make it publicly available. Ideally, I would like to just  move the app to my server, start the app using grunt, and then navigate to `http://myurl.com` from any computer to access the app. What do I need to alter in my project (or what else do I need to setup and configure) to make this happen?

Secondly, in my attempts to make the app public I have moved it over to my server. When I try to run the app with grunt, instead of launching normally as it would on my laptop, I get the error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND (this happens shortly after I get the message 'Mean app started on port 3000').

Could someone please tell me what I'm missing or at least point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit Adding Information**

For information's sake. I have tried to setup the app on two separate CentOS 6.5 servers, neither have been able to launch. So far, I've tried:

- adding a connection object to the root Gruntfile.js with the hostname of the url that I want, as well as 0.0.0.0
- Under node_modules/meanio/lib/mean.js edited the line httpServer.listen(config.http ? config.http.port : config.port, config.hostname); by replacing hostname with my url
- ran `npm config set proxy http://address:8080`
- edited config/env/all.js and changed the module.export http to use port 80 instead of 3000, and disabled the Apache server.
- This is a mean.io project built with the mean.io CLI

**Information about setup**

- All machines that I have put this app on also use Apache which has been tested and are accepting connections on port 80 (successfully).
- Computers that get the ENOTFOUND error are being remotely accessed via ssh while the computers that will run that app are local machines.

**Part of the Question Answered**

I was able to setup a proxy on the Apache server ([see here for example configuration](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache)) and point it to the nodejs app, this allowed me to access the nodejs app by typing in my url.

*However*, the server that I'd like to put this app on still does not run the app. Is there something about a MEAN stack that requires the app to be launched locally? Also, aside from the fact that production traffic goes through port 80, why wouldn't I be able to just open port 3000 and forward it to my development machine?

Comment: for real sites, you don't deploy on port 3000, you deploy on port 80. Or you use a proxy pass-through to ensure that requests on port 80 get linked internally to port 3000

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans true, but even when switching to port 80 I receive the same error

Comment: sounds like you've done some things you haven't mentioned in your post, then. Want to add more details on all the things you tried so far and what your real website deployment setup is?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, honestly I've tried more things than I can remember, but I added some more info. One thing that I can draw back to is the fact that this app has worked on one centOS virtual machine and one laptop running fedora. However, the other two CentOS servers that are public facing are not able to start the app. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by real website deployment setup.

Comment: to figure this problem out, what happens when you make a temp dir like `test`, drop in an index.html with text `<h1>yup</h1>` and then run something like `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`, then access the machine on the port that opens (after making sure the router allows connections to that port for that LAN ip)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks to your comment and some sleep, I was able to think up some more information. I was also running apache on these machines and they were accepting requests on port 80. I've put more details in my post if you're interested.

Comment: any particular data on what the server you want it on is? (digital ocean droplet running nginx and node on centos, dreamhost VPS ubuntu, etc?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans centOS virtual machine with Apache is what I'm trying to make this happen on.

Comment: as a node app in its own VM, Apache's actually going to do more bad than good if it's in the same VM. Node already acts as the server daemon, so all you need in the VM is the `node app` process set to use port 80 through something like --port=80 with `process.env` parsing for that port number (or even just hardcoded). If you need proxy routing in front of it (say, to do domain-to-process resolution, etc) you want something like Nginx instead of Apache.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans fair enough. Actually I only said Apache because that was the only way I could kind of get this to work, I'd be fine with just being able to run the app through node with no proxy.

Comment: if the VM is running `node app`, it will serve content on the active port *provided* that the VM's ports are routed to the internet correctly, so that's a thing you'd need to verify in the host controller.